# awk pattern matching one file to another then save the difference in new file

Tags: awk

```
$ cat File1
781789
989778
898989

$ cat File2
AA^ABB^ACC^A781789^B781782^AEE^AFF^A781789^B781782AA^ABB^ACC^A7817891^B7817821^AEE^AFF^A7817891^B781782AA^ABB^ACC^A781789^B898989^AEE^AFF^A781789^B898989^B898923
```

- Field Separator: "^A" or "\x01"
- Record Separator: "^B" or "\x02"

I would like to create a resultant file "File3" where records from "File1" DOES NOT match any  of the records for Column number 4 and 7 in "File2". If the record matches then DO NOT consider.

Expected output:

```
$ cat File3
AA^ABB^ACC^A7817891^B7817821^AEE^AFF^A7817891^B781782
```

Tried with the below awk code, where I am able to parse "File2" with field separators, but not able to match records from "File1" to "File2".

`awk 'BEGIN { FS="\x01"} NR==FNR{A[$4]~/$0/;next}{print A[$0]} File1 File2 > File3'`

`awk 'BEGIN { FS="\x01"} NR==FNR{A[$7]~/$0/;next}{print A[$0]} File1 File2 > File3'`

Requesting help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your text blocks legibly.

Comment: are the entries in file #1 really on one line, or are they on separate lines (ie, 1 entry per line)? does the second file really have multiple lines with the record break (^B) all over the place, or does the second file consist of a single (really long) line?

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes File1 is structured in such a way that there 1 entry per line. 
File2 consists of a really long line but in order to separate columns which are array based we use ^B as a separator only to those fields.

Comment: given `^A` is a field delimiter, and `^B` is a record delimiter, it appears (to me) that file2 records consist of 4 fields but ... you've stated you want to ignore records based on the contents of field 4 **and field 7** ... but there doesn't appear to be a **field 7**; please update the question with either data showing (at least) 7 fields or update the description with the correct field #(s)

Comment: I've edited the question to show what the data actually looks like; I'm assuming, based on the hex codes you've got in your `awk` scripts that the `^A` and `^B` are really control codes and not literal 2-character strings; please update the textual strings if I made a mistake with the edits ...

Comment: @markp-fuso 
Since '^A' is field delimiter, if you see in File2 we have 7 columns (each column separated with ^A)

Comment: @markp-fuso 
yes thats correct ^A, ^B are hidden characters in the file and not literal strings.

Comment: I'm only seeing 4 fields in the first 5 records and 1 field in the last 2 records; I'll post this in the first part of my answer ... still writing ...

Comment: I don't see how you can get your desired output from your given sample data.

Comment: @markp-fuso yes waiting on ur response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my `file2` and replaced the literal strings `^A` and `^B` with their corresponding control characters `0x01` and `0x02`.  I've also verified that my `file2` has just the one line of data.

We'll start with an `awk` script to verify we've got our field and record separators defined correctly, show how many fields make up each record, and show the contents of the each field:

```
awk '
BEGIN   {  FS="\x01" ;  RS="[\x02|\n]"           # define input field/record delimiters,
                                                 # add "\n" in case the sole line ends in a "\n"

          OFS="-"    ; ORS="\n"   }              # define output field/record delimiters
                                                 # solely for visual purposes of this test

        { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }     # print line
' file2
```

This generates:

```
A-BB-CC-781789---                # 1st 6 records have 4 fields
781782-EE-FF-781789---
781782A-BB-CC-7817891---         # we should see this record in our final output (below)
7817821-EE-FF-7817891---         # we should see this record in our final output (below)
781782A-BB-CC-781789---
898989-EE-FF-781789---
898989------                     # last 2 records have 1 field
898923------
```

Adding `file1` to the mix (storing the values in an array), adding the test for field #4, and adding code to print fields and control codes to stdout:

```
awk '
BEGIN       { FS="\x01"                # define input field separator
              RS="[\x02|\n]"           # define input record separator
              ORS=""                   # will dynamically modify output record separator
            }

FNR==NR     { arr[$1] ; next }         # store file1 values in array arr[]

$4 != ""    { if ($4 in arr)           # if field 4 (file2) is in arr[] (ie, field 4 is in file1)
                 next                  # then skip
              else                     # else add current line to our variable
                 { OFS=""
                   printf "%s", ORS
                   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)    # process variable number of fields
                       { printf "%s%s", OFS, $(i)
                         OFS="\x01"
                       }
                   ORS="\x02"
                 }
            }
' file1 file2
```

**NOTE**: Yeah, this is a bit verbose as I want to make sure it's (a bit) easier to understand the various steps.

This generates:

```
781782ABBCC78178917817821EEFF7817891
```

**NOTE**: This does not match OP's suggested output but can't tell if this is because OP's output was generated from a different set of input or there was an issue with the original cut-n-paste when creating the question; this output does match the 2 records flagged in the output from the first `awk` command (above).

Passing the output through `od -c` (ie, `awk '...' file1 file2 | od -c`):

```
0000000   7   8   1   7   8   2   A 001   B   B 001   C   C 001   7   8
0000020   1   7   8   9   1 002   7   8   1   7   8   2   1 001   E   E
0000040 001   F   F 001   7   8   1   7   8   9   1
0000053
```

**NOTE**: I'm assuming the output should end as shown ... without a `\0x02` nor a `\n`; OP can add a `END { printf ... }` block to add any additional character(s) on the end of the line/file as needed.

Comment: @mark-fuso 
Thanks this is super helpful. One question, when we say "if ($4 in arr)", does this iteratively check each value in column $4 (121312^B3232323) which is "^B" separated in File1 or does this check the complete value of column $4 in File1 "arr"?

Comment: `$4` refers to field #4 of the **current** row/record; `$4 in arr` is checking to see if the entire value of field #4 is an index in the `arr[]` array

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it in `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR { r[$0] = 1; next }
     !((NF >= 4 && $4 in r) || (NF >= 7 && $7 in r))' \
    file1 FS='\x01' RS='\x02' ORS='\x02' file2
```

However, your sample data doesn't produce your listed expected output. In particular, the third record of your `file2` is `781782AA^ABB^ACC^A7817891`, which has a value in the 4th column that doesn't appear in `file1` (And no 7th column; none of the records have that many columns. Some don't even have 4!) and thus should be included in the output going by your description.

Comment: @ Shawn ... Thanks !!!
when we do ($4 in r) this checks the entire 4th column in the file1 array right? The issue I am having is that $4 is a "^B" separated list of values. Is there a way to iteratively check if each of the values in $4 column is present in File1 array i.e. "r" in the above example?

Comment: @adikannanp It checks the 4th field of the current record, one record at a time. You said ^B was the record separator. It's not?

Answer (score 0):

I am not versed in `awk`, but here is how you can do it with `sed` and `grep`:

```sh
egrep -v $'^(\w+\x01){3}((\w+\x01){3})?('$(sed 's/ \+/|/g' < file1)$')[\x02\x01]' file2 > file3
```

The command `egrep -v … file2` matches a regular expression `…` on `file2`, but prints out exactly those lines that do not match (invert). We compose the regular expression from the parts:

1. Three times a word ending with \x01, so we end up in column 4
2. Optionally, another three times a word ending with \x01, so we end up in column 7
3. Any of the records from `file1`
4. A record separator \x02 *or* a field separator \x01 (if last record in column)

To obtain part (3) from `file1` we use `sed` to replace all spaces between the records in the file with a pipe. This results in the format `(abc|def|ghi)`, which in the regular expression expresses a group of alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach!!